# Python loop puzzle variable assigned value unexplainably

Tags: python, loops

Can someone explain to me how this can work

```
dct = {1: 'abc', 2: 'deg'}

result = []

for value in dct.values():
    print(f'\nloop entry: {value}')

    temp = []
    for n, record in enumerate(value):

        print(f'\tsubloop {n} record: {record}        result {result}')

        if n == 0:
            print(f'\t\tresult: {result}')
            result.append(temp)
            print(f'\t\tSAVED temp ({temp}) --->  RESULT: {result}')

        temp.append(f'{record}')
    # end for
# end for


print(f'\n\nafter loops result: {result}')
```

output is

```
loop entry: abc
    subloop 0 record: a        result []
        result: []
        SAVED temp ([]) --->  RESULT: [[]]
    subloop 1 record: b        result [['a']]
    subloop 2 record: c        result [['a', 'b']]

loop entry: deg
    subloop 0 record: d        result [['a', 'b', 'c']]
        result: [['a', 'b', 'c']]
        SAVED temp ([]) --->  RESULT: [['a', 'b', 'c'], []]
    subloop 1 record: e        result [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d']]
    subloop 2 record: g        result [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e']]


after loops result: [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'g']]
```

I need to understand how variable `result` is getting value assigned on every iteration of `subloop` when it supposed to only get assigned on first iteration `if n == 0`.

Comment: `append` does not create a copy of the list. Try it at http://pythontutor.com.

Comment: `result.append(temp)` This appends the actual live `temp` object, not a copy of it.  So later in the loop when more things are added to `temp`, these show up in `result` also.

Comment: @deceze thanks nice tool.

That's what problem with python it uses object for everything.

Comment: That's not a "problem", it's simply what it is. In other languages you need to be aware of other things you can aim at your foot.